# Why are my Google Analytics custom variables not recorded?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm trying to set 5 custom variables for Google Analytics like so:

```
<script>
    //<![CDATA[
    var _gaq=[["_setAccount","UA-XXXXXXXXX-X"],["_trackPageLoadTime"]];
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'categories', 'News', 3]);   
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 2, 'tags', 'something, another, passbook, iphone, ipod, ios6, insider, egift, more things, some other stuff', 3]);  
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 3, 'productcount', 0, 3]);  
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 4, 'isvideo', 'false', 3]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];g.async=1;
g.src=("https:"==location.protocol?"//ssl":"//www")+".google-analytics.com/ga.js";
s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,"script"));
//]]>

</script>
```

I think I've followed all the rules by adding no more than 5 custom vars before the call to trackPageView, but they still don't show up in Google Analytics.

Comment: when did you add them (how long since recording should have started)? and also have you ever tried it with less vars? your use of the `_setCustomVar` is correct in terms of parameters

Comment: On `'productcount'` the CustomVar Value should be a string but it seems to be a number. Try: `_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 3, 'productcount', '0', 3]);`. But I'm not sure if it would break the other good CVs.

Comment: i think you may have something there, @Eduardo

Comment: @Kristian these have been up for about 24 hours now, so should be seeing something

Comment: @Eduardo OK I'll make it a string and see how it goes thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Possibilities:

- Custom Variables can lag behind _trackPageview's showing up in the GA UI. (Source #1)
- If you're using ga_debug.js you can see in your console what's firing back. (Source #2)
- You're bumping up close to the Custom Variable length of 128 with the CustomVar(2).  As this is test data, make sure your real data doesn't go over. (Source #3)
- Eduardo is right that the 0 vs "0" is causing CustomVar(3) to not fire. (Source #2 & Testing)
- _trackPageLoadTime is deprecated (Source #2+3 & Testing)

#### Links/References:

1. [Mastering Google Analytics Custom Variables](http://cutroni.com/blog/2011/05/18/mastering-google-analytics-custom-variables/)
2. [Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna)
3. [Official Google Analytics Custom Variables Documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables)

#### Updated Snippet in Demo Page for Debugger:

*(serve from something that's not localhost or file://)*

```
<html><head><title>Demo</title><script>

var _gaq=[["_setAccount","UA-XXXXXXXXX-X"]];
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'categories', 'News', 3]);   
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 2, 'tags', 'something, another, passbook, iphone, ipod, ios6, insider, egift, more things, some other stuff', 3]);  
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 3, 'productcount', '0', 3]);  
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 4, 'isvideo', 'false', 3]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
(function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];g.async=1;
g.src=("https:"==location.protocol?"//ssl":"//www")+".google-analytics.com/ga.js";
s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,"script"));

</script></head><body><h1>Open your console</h1></body></html>
```

Comment: The GA debugger add on is worth marking this as correct alone!